# How to align center Y of widget to top edge of another

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to achieve effect as shown on the picture:

[image]

Green widget is of fixed size. Blue widget is placed just over green one (with some spacing). Blue widget size can change at runtime. I wan't top edge of yellow widget to be always aligned to center Y of blue widget, regardless of blue widget height.

In case blue widget height would be fixed the solution is pretty simple. But how to achieve this result assuming height of blue widget can change in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Here I think the widget you're looking for is `Positioned` it's allow you to define a position in a `Stack` Widget and you can define height inside. Here are the link to [Video widget of the week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgtPleVwxBQ)
and [Official doc](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html)

I am thinking to an other trick: You can define a `height` variable for you blue box and you can set a `marginTop` to your yellow Widget at precisely `height/2` then your yellow block would always let half your blue box out.

(It's working with this components but if it's included with more Widgets it may not do the trick)

Hope it helps !!

Comment: If I understood the question right, the blue widget can be any widget e.g. Column and therefore we are not able to specify the height of the blue box.

Comment: @Niklas Oh yeah you're right then maybe with an `IntrinsicHeight` to wrap it

Comment: @Niklas You are right, the blue widget might be any widget with height dependant on its internal content.

Comment: @Ferdi I don't see how IntrinsicHeight widget could help here

Comment: To define the height of the blue widget and use the trick I define before